# tell socat to stop on connection refuse with fork enabled

Tags: port-forwarding, fork, socat

I'm using this instruction to forward a port to another, both on a local machine:

```
socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:80,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:127.0.0.1:8000
```

I need to keep the port open unless the destination port get closed (connection refuse).

Is it possible to ask `socat` to terminate on connection refuse (with fork enabled)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible with current versions

Comment: Thank you for answer and for `socat`. I hope you will add this feature in the near future :)